# Getting Error while deploying angular 2 app on heroku

Tags: angular, heroku, typescript

I am facing  `sh: 1: tsc: not found Error` while deploying angular 2 app on heroku and I am using node version : v7.2.0 npm Version:v4.0.3.

[Image of the error on heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AOlx.png)

Can any one tell me,How can i fix this issue ?

Comment: It looks like typescript isn't installed on your heroku. Note: `tsc` is the typescript compiler.

Comment: @Dinistro I have written all dependencies in my package.json file but i don't  know why its giving this error.you can see my json file -> http://ideone.com/JvbbQk

Comment: It expects typescript to be installed globally. If you have enough rights, try to run `npm install typescript -g` on heroku.

Comment: @Dinistro I have installed on heroku using command "heroku run npm install typescript -g"  but still i am getting the same error.

Comment: I'm sorry, then I can't help you

Comment: Please try heroku local web and let

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the process in which Heroku installs and removes dev-dependencies. When you push to Heroku it installs dev-dependencies, runs your build script then removes dev-dependencies.

My issue was that I had a "prestart" script that relied on the dev-dependencies. This essentially made the build script run again but since by this time the dev-dependencies are gone, I got the "not found" errors on tsc and other modules.

I removed the "prestart" script and now all is well.